# Need to bind WPF RadGridView to XML doc and display attribute values in the grid

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, radgridview

I'm working on a a WPF application and need to bind a RadGridView to an XML document and, for my columns, display data from the attributes of the node.

Currently it's giving me to correct number of rows but instead of the values I'm looking for it displays the string "System.Xml.XmlElement"

Here's my XAML.

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="uxSettings" ItemsSource="{Binding XmlSettings}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
RowIndicatorVisibility="Visible"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="150" 
ShowGroupPanel="False" Width="350"  Margin="10"  IsFilteringAllowed="False">
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@ID}" Header="Item Name" Width="300"/>
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

And here's the xml I'm binding to.

```
<settings>
<setting ID="OutputXOffset" value="12" />
<setting ID="OutputYOffset" value="12" />
</settings>
```

I'm actually binding to an ObservableCollection collection that I'm populating like this.

```
public ObservableCollection<XmlNode> PopulateXmlSettings(XmlDocument settingsDoc)
```

{
    XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();
    provider.IsAsynchronous = false;
    provider.Document = settingsDoc;
    provider.XPath = "settings/setting";

```
return  new ObservableCollection<XmlNode>((IEnumerable<XmlNode>)provider.Data);
```

}

Ideally I want the ID's "OutputXOffset and OutputYOffset" to be viewable and only the values "12" to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by first including your solution namespace in the window definition and then including the observablecollection collection class in resources like following

```
<Window.Resources>
     <solutionNameSpace:ClassName x:Key="Class1" />
</Window.Resources>
.
.
```

Then updating control like following

```
<telerik:RadGridView ....... ItemSource="{StaticResource Class1}" ....>
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" .....>
</telerik.RadView.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding directly to XmlNodes, create your own type that exposes the appropriate properties needed for your UI and bind to a collection of those.

<strike>Another option is to inherit from XmlNode and override ToString() to return the value you want to display in your column... but I don't recommend this. I prefer creating POCOs and populating them with data from the datasource and binding to the POCOs.</strike>

Scratch that; it seems you can't inherit from XmlNode anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the Telerik control you might want to report. To test this I wrote your xml like;

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlSettings" XPath="/settings/setting">
  <x:XData>
    <settings xmlns="">
      <setting ID="OutputXOffset" value="12"/>
      <setting ID="OutputYOffset" value="12"/>
    </settings>
  </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

and then bound to it with both a DataGrid and a telerik RadGridView like;

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlSettings}}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@value}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlSettings}}">
  <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@value}"/>
  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

and the DataGrid works but the RadGridView doesn't and instead returns an xmlElement as you said. To get at the xmlElement's value I figured I'd write a simple Converter (IValueConverter) for the binding. Once I did this I found that the converter receives the entire "setting" element instead of the attribute pointed to by the XPath so the converter would look like;

```
Imports System.Xml

<ValueConversion(GetType(XmlElement), GetType(String))> _
Public Class xmlElement2String
    Implements IValueConverter

  Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, 
      parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
      ) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim anXmlElement As XmlElement = TryCast(value, XmlElement)
    If anXmlElement is Nothing then Return Binding.DoNothing
    Return anXmlElement.SelectSingleNode(CType(parameter,String)).Value
  End Function

  Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, 
      parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
      ) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    throw new System.NotImplementedException("Not implemented.")
  End Function
End Class
```

so you would add a reference in your Xaml to the value converter like;

```
<local:xmlElement2String x:Key="xmlElement2String"/>
```

and change your bindings to;

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@ID, 
    Converter={StaticResource xmlElement2String}, ConverterParameter=@ID}"/>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding
    Converter={StaticResource xmlElement2String}, ConverterParameter=@value}"/>
```

notice that for "ID" I left the XPath statement in and for "value" I left it off and it makes no difference. Hope this helps...